# How do I split a string without keeping the delimiter?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split, delimiter

In Ruby, how do I split a string and not keep the delimiter in the resulting split array?  I though tthis was the default, but when I try

```
2.4.0 :016 >   str = "a b c"
 => "a b c"
2.4.0 :017 > str.split(/([[:space:]]|,)+/)
 => ["a", " ", "b", " ", "c"]
```

I see the spaces included in my result.  I would like the result to simply be

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`String#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) documentation:

> If pattern contains groups, the respective matches will be returned in the array as well.

Answering your explicitly stated question: do not match the group:

```
#           ⇓⇓ HERE
str.split(/(?:[[:space:]]|,)+/)
```

or, even without groups:

```
str.split(/[[:space:],]+/)
```

or, in more Rubyish way:

```
'a    b, c,d   e'.split(/[\p{Space},]+/)
#⇒ ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Answer (score 2):

`String#split`splits on white-space by default, so don 't bother with a regex:

```
"a b c".split # => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this please

```
str.split(' ')
```

Comment: You've fundamentally changed my output though.  Here you are only splitting on a single breaking space.  I want to split on a lot of spaces (breaking and non-breaking or commas).